# When I change Localizable.strings (en) another Localizable.strings (ru) changes too

Tags: iphone, ios, multilingual, localizable.strings

I was trying to add multi languages (en, ru) support to my iOS project. I used tutorials for this issue:

- http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

So I have to files localizable.strings in different folders.

But when I change Localizable.strings (en.lproj) in project, Localizable.strings (ru.lproj) changes too. So they are the same. I can't understand WHY???

The locations and full paths which are displayed in xcode are correct. It seems that changes the same file. Because when I save Localizable.strings in xcode, in finder I see that one file is changed.

What's the problem??? What do I wrong??? Could you help me?

P.S. Even I rename files to different names, problem the same.

P.P.S. As an example I used project "ILikeIt". And even I open this project and look at Localizable.strings (in this project) I see Localizable.strings from my project. It seems very weird.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got confused with the file name. It is **`Localizable.strings`**
not <strike>`Localization.strings`</strike>.

Or perhaps you created *aliases* instead of copies when you first duplicated the original `Localizable.strings` file?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake in my post. I use the right name Localizable.strings.
Thanks.

Comment: When I add files, I check "Copy items into destination group's folder" and select "Create groups for any added folder". Is it correct?
But when I add second file Localizable.strings it marks as red in "Build Phases".

Comment: Here is your problem. Delete all these files. Add a `ru` language version in Xcode (select the only Localizable.string file, right pane, Document Inspector, press the plus button, select language). Now just edit these files in Xcode, copy / paste from the files you already have. In this way the files will be created in the right places with the right names.

Comment: I've started from the previous release (without multilang support). There was no file Localizable.strings in my project. I added this file to the project (File -> New -> New File (string file)). Then I clicked "+" in the right column and added localization (English was added by default and then added russian). The files were created in the right places. But when I edit one file in xcode another file (in xcode) changes too. Problem the same. Why??? I don't know what's wrong...
Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart your Mac? Did you try quitting Xcode and editing with another text editor?